# How to group by on a particular column and select top 80 percentile based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to do group by and then within that group, selecting top 85 percentile value from a particular column and getting all records.

I am using below query , it works but when I try to run for 100 million rows it take hours and still not get results.

```
o <- r %>% 
  select(everything()) %>%
  group_by(loan_num_srvcr) %>%
  filter(diff_in_date > quantile(diff_in_date, .85))
```

another approach

```
k <- r[ave(1:nrow(r), r$loan_num_srvcr, FUN = seq_along) <= r$diff_in_date, ]
```

another approach

some one suggested me to group by and then split on each group and get result and then `rbind` all the rows, I tried but not getting the desired results in limited time frame.

Comment: I would suggest `data.table` or at least the `dtplyr` package, which uses `data.table` with `dplyr` API. Also, `select(everything())` literally does nothing.

Comment: can you elaborate more

Comment: See the answer provided below.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(r)

system.time({
      r[, Q85 := quantile(diff_in_date, .85), by=loan_num_srvcr][diff_in_date > Q85]
   })
user  system elapsed 
5.02    0.51    4.94
```

---

```
dim(r)
[1] 100000000        3
```